# Using nested generics in java

Tags: java, vaadin, nested-generics

In Vaadin 8.5.1 we have a Grid component which has this method to add new columns to the grid.

```
<V> Grid.​Column<​T​,V>     addColumn(​ValueProvider<​T​,V> valueProvider)
```

A full examples looks like this:

```
// Have some data
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
    new Person("Nicolaus Copernicus", 1543),
    new Person("Galileo Galilei", 1564),
    new Person("Johannes Kepler", 1571));

// Create a grid bound to the list
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(people);
grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");
grid.addColumn(Person::getBirthYear).setCaption("Year of birth");

layout.addComponent(grid);
```

and this works fine.
But what I'm now trying to implement is, when the Person class extends another class which is common to most objects.

For example:

```
public class NamedClass
{
    ...
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Person extends NamedClass
{
    ...
    public int getBirthYear()
    {
         return birthYear;
    }
}
```

Now I wish to make a grid helper class, which does the

```
grid.addColumn(NamedClass::getName).setCaption("Name");
```

for all descendent class, als the other properties are handled my a extension of this.

I tried with:

```
public class ANamedGridHelper<T extends NamedClass> {

    public Column<T, ?> mapProperties(Grid grid) {
       return grid.addColumn(NamedClass::getName).setId("name");
    }
}
```

and

```
 public class PersonGridHellper<Person>
 {
     ----
 }
```

but it won't compile the `ANamedGridHelper` class

```
org/aarboard/gridtest1/ANamedGridHelper.java:[19,19] no suitable method found for addColumn(NamedClass::getName)
    method com.vaadin.ui.Grid.addColumn(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String is not a functional interface)
    method com.vaadin.ui.Grid.addColumn(com.vaadin.data.ValueProvider) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
          method getName in class org.aarboard.gridtest1.NamedClass cannot be applied to given types
            required: no arguments
            found: java.lang.Object
            reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
org/aarboard/gridtest1/ANamedGridHelper.java:[19,30] invalid method reference
  non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: For starters:  abstract classes can't have a method body.

Comment: @Makoto I think you meant "abstract _methods_ can't have a body."

Comment: @MikeHarris:  Yes.  Yes, I did.

Comment: try like: ```? extends NamedClass``` but not sure if it will work if you use a child class, so maybe you will need to type as ```V extends NamedClass```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unknown for compiler type of `T`. Since the method `getName` comes from `NamedClass`, you have to do the same either in the method `ANamedGridHelper::mapProperties:

```
public class ANamedGridHelper<T extends NamedClass> {
    public Column<T, ?> mapProperties(Grid<T> grid, T bo) {
       return grid.addColumn(NamedClass::getName).setId("name");
    }
}
```

Few notes:

- A class having `abstract` method must be `abstract` as well.
- An `abstract` method has no body - is without implementation and awaits to be overridden.

I had to also add the  to the Grid parameter of the method, now it works as expected.

Comment: This does not compile, it complains about `no suitable method found for addColumn(NamedClass::getName)` (I added the full error message to the question)

Comment: Thanks, now works after adding <T> to the Grid parameter